# angular2 need to access the child value in parent class

Tags: angular2-forms

Here, I need to access the child value in parent class.
But I am not able to get it. If I am using directives it showing error.
Can someone please help me in displaying the child values in parent component and how the child value can be validated in reactive form?

**parent.html :**

```
<browser  [template]="coreActivity" (onselect)="onselect($event)" ></browser>
```

**parent.ts :**

```
 onselect(select: any)
 {
    console.log(select.value);
 }
```

**child.html :**

```
<md-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="100px">
    <md-grid-tile *ngFor="let core of template" (click)="selectcore(core)">
       {{core.value}}
     </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

**child.ts :**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'template-browser',
  templateUrl: './template-browser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./template-browser.component.css']
})
export class TemplateBrowserComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() template;

  @Output() notify: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();  
  constructor(private community: CreateCommunityComponent ) { }  
  selectcore(core: any) {
      // alert(core.value);
      this.notify.emit(core.value);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are passing Values through `EventEmitter` you need to pass it with Child component Declaration in `parent.html`.

```
<browser (notify)="onSelect($event)"  [template]="coreActivity" (onselect)="onselect($event)" ></browser>
```

And in function under **parent.ts :**

```
 onSelect(select)
 {
    console.log(select.value);
 }
```

Comment: i am able to access the child value into parent.How to validate <browser (notify)="onSelect($event)"  [template]="coreActivity" (onselect)="onselect($event)" ></browser> using react form validation?????? when i try doing the validation it is giving error ; ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'template'

Comment: Can you elaborate it more? If possible create new thread for that

Comment: can you please look into it:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645272/reactive-form-validation-angular2

Answer (score 0):

In order to access `child.html` in parent, you need to create a another component and use that component name as tag in parent.
like component name is "child"
keep `<child></child>` in parent

Comment: Hello can you please provide more details ? Possible code as well