# Reactive form-validation-angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am able to get the values from the child but I need to validate the values in my parent component that is present or not.

**parent.html :**

```
<browser (notify)="onselect($event)"  [template]="coreActivity" (onselect)="onselect($event)" formControlName="template" ></browser>
```

**parent.ts :**

```
export class CreateCommunityComponent implements OnInit {  userForm: FormGroup;  public tagarray=[];   coreActivity = [
   {value: 'Professional', viewValue: 'Professional', tool: 'Forum' },
   {value: 'Travel', viewValue: 'Travel', tool: 'quora'},
   {value: 'Arts', viewValue: 'Arts', tool: 'stackoverflow'},
   {value: 'Technology', viewValue: 'Technology', tool: 'quora'},
   {value: 'Business', viewValue: 'Business', tool: 'Forum'},
   {value: 'Science', viewValue: 'Science', tool: 'quora'},
   {value: 'Education', viewValue: 'Education', tool: 'quora'}
 ];    visibility = [
     {value: 'Public', viewValue: 'Public'},
     {value: 'Private', viewValue: 'Private'},
     {value: 'Moderate', viewValue: 'Moderate'}
   ];    tags = [
     {value: 'tag-one', viewValue: 'tagone'},
     {value: 'tag-two', viewValue: 'tagtwo' },
     {value: 'tag-three', viewValue: 'tagthree'}
   ];
 constructor(private dialog: MdDialog, private fb: FormBuilder,private router: Router) {    this.createForm();    }  createForm() {
       this.userForm = this.fb.group({
         domainName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-z.]{8,20}')]],
         communityName: ['', Validators.required],
         Purpose: ['', Validators.required],
         visibility: ['Public', Validators.required],
         template: ['',Validators.required],
         tagSelection: ['', Validators.required],
         termscondition: ['', Validators.required]
       });
   }
//  check whether the card is clickable or not 
onselect(selectedTemplate: any)
{
  console.log(selectedTemplate);
  return selectedTemplate;
}
```

It is giving error while I am validating the child value is present or not:

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'template'

Comment: please provide some more html content

Comment: Have you imported `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`?

Comment: Could you add the template for the child as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ngDefaultControl` to your `<browser>` tag.

```
<browser ngDefaultControl (notify)="onselect($event)"  
  [template]="coreActivity" (onselect)="onselect($event)" 
formControlName="template" ></browser>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: i am using formgroup to validate my form fields and i need  to validate the template field using formcontrol

Comment: Can you remove and try that ?

Comment: getting an error :ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'template'

Comment: Same error you are getting when you are removing the `formGorup?`